# Cannot cast to Chromecast on local WiFi network from Pi 2 running Jessie

Tags: pi-2, wifi, raspbian-jessie, chromium, chromecast

I've got a Pi 2 running Jessie, which I did a dist-upgrade on just yesterday (24 Feb 2017).  So I'm running the latest stuff.

On it is installed Chromium 56.0.2924.84.  I'd like to cast from this device to a Chromecast (firmware version 1.22.80438) that I bought a couple years ago.  So far, no joy.

I can cast to my device from everything else in the house that I've tried: my iPhone 6, an Intel Linux box running 14.04, a Windows 10 laptop, an Android tablet.  But Chromium on the Pi never even detects the Chromecast on the local network.

The Pi is connecting up to the network just fine - I can browse, view YouTube videos in the browser window, etc.  But it just never detects the Chromecast at all.

Any suggestions on how I can get this to work?  Thanks.

My WiFi connection is via Edimax USB dongle, if that matters...

Answer (score 1):

Use mkchromecast. It supports both audio and video. Get it [here](http://mkchromecast.com/). It is a python script which calls various programs.
It will never use as much memory as chrome, but you may need to overclock and heatsink your Pi.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the browser [Cast Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-cast/boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd) that hopefully you can install on the Pi's Chromium.

Comment: The Cast extension has been discontinued.  Since Chromium 51, the Cast functionality has been incorporated into the browser itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug in Chromium discussed at raspberrypi.org:

[Cast to ChromeCast not functioning in Chromium](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=177268&p=1235173#p1235173) .

It might have been reported and fixed at

[Debian Bug report logs - #870619
Cast to chromecast device does not work](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=870619)

and so will hopefully start working again in the future, when the fix makes it into Raspbian.